# Pipeline failed

Tags: gitlab, cypress, cicd

I am trying to run cypress test scripts on Gitlab CICD  Pipeline but this error occured
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrRkh.png)

Here is my code on gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: docker:18.09
stages:
  - test

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run test
```

Comment: use an `image` that has npm for e.g. node

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cypress provide some custom docker image to use to avoid dependencies issues. You can check for them here [cypress docker images](https://docs.cypress.io/examples/examples/docker#Images)

I also faced many weird issues with the implementation of a `cypress` job to run in CI. In order to not reinvent the wheel, you can use the [cypress run job](https://api.r2devops.io/job/r/r2devops-bot/cypress_run/latest.yaml) I shared in this opensource community hu for CI/CD jobs.It's customizable, you just need to include the job url in your pipeline and override some little varaiables, as mentioned in the related documentation of the job.

You should have something like that:

```
include:
   - remote: 'https://api.r2devops.io/job/r/r2devops-bot/cypress_run/latest.yaml'
cypress_run:
   variables:
       BASE_URL: '<your_server_url>
```